# Where is TeXworks' template folder on Linux?

Tags: templates, texworks, linux

I've spent about an hour in total searching the Net for an answer and searching through my computer's folders, to no avail. Where is the template folder for TeXworks on Linux?

My distribution is Mint 19.1, and I used the `TeXlive-full` package from the `mintinstall` Software Manager.

Comment: I vote to close this message because, it does not involve any TeX related issues. Hence, it belongs to some other SE which deals with these issues (sorry @ahorn I don't know which SE it is).

Comment: @Raaja Since there is a texworks tag I assume such questions are accepted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your exact setup, but for me the path is `$HOME/.TeXworks/templates`. (Note that some file explorers hide directories starting with a dot by default.)

Comment: Seems like I need to display my hidden folders.